# Same window.addEventListener For 2 html files

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

Hello Everyone I have this problem that is just bugging me and I cant get it figured out. I looked everywhere and couldnt find an answer.

I have 2 html files and 1 external javascript file....

This is the first html file

```
<!doctype html>

<head>
    <title>.....</title>
    <script src="externalJsFile"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="button" value="button1" id="button1">
    </div>
</body>

<html>
```

here is my second html file that links to the same external javsascript file

```
<!doctype html>

<head>
    <title>.....</title>
    <script src="externalJsFile"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="button" value="button2" id="button2">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my external javascript file

```
window.addEventListener("load", setFunctions, false);


function setFunctions() {
    var button1 = document.getElementById("button1");
    var button2 = document.getElementById("button2");

    button1.addEventListener("click", sayHello, false);
    button2.addEventListener("click", sayHello, false);
}


function sayHello() {
    alert("hello");
}
```

When I visit each html page to click the button to see the hello popup box it only works in one of the pages. In the javascript if i switch around the order of the event listeners on the buttons then the popup will only work on the other page now!! someone please help!! Do I need separate external javascript files for each html page when a window event listener is used???

Comment: Why this is tagged with `jQuery`?

Comment: I don't notice any opening `<html>` tags ....

Comment: @GaurangTandon — The start tag for the HTML element is defined as optional.

Comment: @Quentin I know, but I just brought it to OPs notice that he should add them.

Answer (score 2):

In the *first* HTML page, `button1` is a button and `button2` is `null`.

`button1.addEventListener("click", sayHello, false);` binds the event handler, then `button2.addEventListener("click", sayHello, false);` errors. Since there is no more code in the function, this has no noticeable effect unless you are watching the JS console.

In the *second* HTML page, it is the other way around: `button2` is a button and `button1` is `null`.

`button1.addEventListener("click", sayHello, false);` errors, and it never reaches the next line.

Test to see `if (button1) {}` and `if (button2) {}` before binding … and look at your JavaScript error console when you have problems.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I added the if statements and it fixed it. Thanks!